# Parent form closing when child form closes

Tags: c#, forms, event-handling

In my C# application, I have the following method that is called when the main form closes.

```
private void FormMain_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{ 
        // Show this dialog when the user tries to close the main form
        Form testForm = new FormTest();
        testForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        testForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

This creates a dialog window that will show when the main form is closing.  However, my issue is that when the user closes `testForm`, the main form closes immediately after.  I've tried all sorts of variants of `e.Cancel = true;` and such, and still cannot cancel the main form closing.

Any ideas?

---

Edit: it looks like I'm running into an issue using two `ShowModal()`'s in succession.  Looking into the issue...

---

Edit: Used `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;` and it seems to have fixed my problem.  It is apparently a known issue in WinForms when opening a modal dialog from a modal dialog.

Comment: I suggest you put your solution in an `answer` to your `question` and mark it as the correct answer. This way, other people will know that this question has been answered already - and also see what you did to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This code works fine with me. I think there is a problem in another part of your code.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Form testForm = new FormTest();
    testForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    testForm.ShowDialog();

    e.Cancel = testForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could to be handled by the children too from the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.aspx):

> If a form has any child or owned
>   forms, a FormClosing event is also
>   raised for each one. If any one of the
>   forms cancels the event, none of the
>   forms are closed. Therefore the
>   corresponding FormClosed events are
>   not sent to any of the forms.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you mention in your question that you have tried to use 'e.Cancel = true;' However, the following code works in my environment (.NET 4.0, Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7):

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
     // Show this dialog when the user tries to close the main form
     Form testForm = new FormTest();
     testForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
     testForm.ShowDialog();
     e.Cancel = true;
 }
```

If this doesn't work in your case you may have other event handlers at work. In that case try this code in a newly generated Windows Forms Application.

Comment: Also, .NET 4.6, VS 2015, Win 7 (after almost 6 years you get an up vote :) Note, that you need to track result[s] of any child forms that got opened.